# How do you tell the difference between HTML tags and text surrounded in <> in wikitext?

Tags: html, markdown, wikitext

I have to interpret wikitext into readable speech, and there is quite an assortment of HTML tags available, such as `<math chem>` or `<poem>`. Thus a constant issue is ascertaining what is a tag, and what is text. For example:

```
A propositional fallacy is an error in logic that concerns compound propositions. 
For a compound proposition to be true, the truth values of its constituent parts 
must satisfy the relevant logical connectives that occur in it 
(most commonly: <b><and>, <or>, <not>, <only if>, <if and only if></b>).
```

What is the proper way to ascertain what is text and what is tag? Is there a list available of all the html tags available, or should I do checks for the presence of a `/>` self closing tag, or a `</and>` closing tag, or something else entirely?

Comment: I'd say if the document is coming in that way, it's XML and there's nothing you can do.  In your example, the last line should read `<b>&lt;and&gt;, &lt;or&gt;...</b>`

Comment: @Scott I unfortunately do not control what text is given to me. I have to interpret it to the best of my ability. Also, correct me if I am wrong, but shouldn't xml place all tags on new lines?

Comment: create an array of all HTML tags and then search for them in the text :D

Comment: I'm not sure, but even if that were the case, there's no guarantee that it'll actually come in that way.  Maybe it would help to post the code that is sending + receiving the wikitext?  It really should be encoded properly - [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies#Propositional_fallacies) encodes them in the source.

Comment: @Nicholas Also not possible, I can create my own `<blah>` tag if I so desired, or a Web Component `<my-blah>` which is valid!

Comment: @Scott To create that web component, would that have to be done in the page HTML? If so, then I could do a check for that...

Comment: At that point you're basically doing the job of a browser by parsing pure text into some kind of DOM and running scripts on it (this will be absolutely brutal).  If you're using something like jQuery's `.text()` to get that content, try `.html()` to get the encoded entities.

Comment: @Scott Also yes you found the source. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=List_of_fallacies&action=edit provides the actual source I grab, and they have not escaped the < and > in this particular article, and I do not have the resources available to correct each article I come across with poor encoding standards.

Comment: It won't be encoded in the editor, but will be encoded if you're scraping the page - try running `$("#mw-content-text > p:nth-child(12)").html()` in the browser console from the main article.

Comment: @Scott The brutal part was building an interpreter, which I can say was a mistake, but not the worst thing (And with a few benefits). A proper avenue would be to use the interpreter that has already been made. I'm not using JQuery, but qt, but I have something like what you suggested. I only use it on certain things however.

Comment: @Scott Great suggestion and fascinating result. If I can find a way to link a solution like that into Qt or a shell command, that would suffice as an excellent answer worth accepting.

Comment: @Akiva Sadly I know nothing about Qt, sorry! Good luck though!